# Integrating Mail Chimp API into Django Application.

Tags: python, django, mailchimp

Any one has got idea about,How to Integrate mail chimp api into django app? i have installed **django-mailchimp-v1.3** on my app, but not able to proceed with the rest(views an all), How to add contacts(list) to the mailing list? Mail chimp documentation has got less details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would take a look at the following page of the author:

https://github.com/piquadrat/django-mailchimp#using-them

There is a nice example of how to add/subscribe to the mailing list.

Comment: yeah.! thanks for the answer. but how can i create a new list from my app? in this document they have mentioned only about adding contacts to the existing list by providing that list id. i want to create a new list and add contacts to it from my django app.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use MailSnake.

https://github.com/michaelhelmick/python-mailsnake

Answer (score 0):

django-mailchimp-v1.3 by default doesn't support django 1.7 and above. There is extended version with added support for 1.7 and probably above versions. It can be installed using:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/ephemerallabs/django-mailchimp.git
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using django-mailchimp package use mailchimp package for integrating MailChimp to your Django site.

First, you have create an account on MailChimp, create the List there, and thereafter get the List Key and API key of your account.

Install the package to integrate MailChimp into your Django site

```
pip install mailchimp
```

Then send a request to connect with your list in MailChimp

```
import mailchimp

API_KEY = <<Your MailChimp API Key>>
LIST_ID = <<Your List Key>>
api = mailchimp.Mailchimp(API_KEY)
api.lists.subscribe(LIST_ID, {'email': 'xyz@gmail.com'})
```

Full Tutorial on this Topic: https://djangopy.org/package-of-week/how-to-integrate-mailchimp-on-django-to-increase-subscribers/